# Logical implication in existence of partial derivatives with non differentiable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, logic, continuity

I ask for some help in unknotting this chain of reasonings, in particular in spotting logical errors due to wrong implications and possible mathematical misbeliefs about this problem.

*Theorem*: If $f(x, y)$ has partial derivatives (id est, they exist) at a point $(x_0, y_0)$, and they are continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0, y_0)$.

This is an IF - THEN, hence the condition *partial derivatives exist and they are continuous* is sufficient but not necessary.

Indeed I know that $f$ can be differentiable even if partial derivatives are not continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$.

Another fact is: if $f$ is not continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$, then $f$ is not differntiable at $(x_0, y_0)$.

Another fact: the existence of partial derivatives does not guarantees that they are also continuous.

Now, at this point I do ask:

- Suppose $f$ is not continuos at $(x_0, y_0)$, then if partial derivatives of $f$ do both exist at $(x_0, y_0)$, then at least one of them is not continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$

Is this generally valid? Is this generally wrong? Is this always wrong?

**ADD**

I found this, that might help: [function not continuous, partial derivatives exists -> partial derivatives not continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150670/function-not-continuous-partial-derivatives-exists-partial-derivatives-not-c)

My question still remains in the sense of the **at least one**. Is it valid to say "at least one" instead of "$f$ hasn't continuous partial derivatives"? The second statement seems global to me, in the sense that **ALL** the partial derivatives are discontinuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$, then if partial derivatives of $f$ do both exist at $(x_0, y_0)$, then at least one of them is not continuous at $(x_0, y_0).$
>
> Is this generally valid?

Yes, because:

> *Theorem*: If $f(x, y)$ has partial derivatives at $(x_0, y_0)$, and they are continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $(x_0, y_0).$

At $(x_0, y_0),$ if $f$ is not differentiable, then $f$ has no partial derivatives or at least one of its partial derivatives is discontinuous.

> Another fact: if $f$ is not continuous at $(x_0, y_0)$, then $f$ is not differentiable at $(x_0, y_0).$

Therefore, at $(x_0, y_0),$ if $f$ is discontinuous, then $f$ has no partial derivatives or at least one of its partial derivatives is discontinuous.

Hence, at $(x_0, y_0),$ if $f$ is discontinuous and has partial derivatives, then at least one of its partial derivatives is discontinuous.